# Clear iTunes balance

Tags: itunes, ipad

I am trying to change my iTunes account country.  It tells me I need to clear my balance before I can change countries.

I have an UK account with  £0.44 in it. I can't find anything cheaper than  £0.49 to purchase.
So how do I clear my balance so I can change my region?

Comment: How does iTunes keep balances? Is this what gift cards can do to you?

Comment: I have been perpetually trying to tell iTunes that I have been living in Ireland for the past seven years. But since my credit cards, although registered at an Irish address are from the continent, I remain an iTunes German. Now I have an Irish VISA debit card but iTunes doesn't acccept VISA debit.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a help request to apple iTunes customer support.
As promised they responded within 24 hours and resolved my issue.

They cleared the 44p from my account thus making me able to change my country.
Thanks iTunes Support!

[Link to submit support request](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/contact.html?form=account&topic=iTunes%20Store%20Account%20and%20Billing&subtopic=Managing%20your%20Account)